java lombok annotation throwing nullpointer exception
I'm using lombok annotations in my java code, yet i'm getting the null pointer exception. I can't figure out where i'm going wrong. i've even tried using @Autowired annotation, but is of now use. did any one face similar issue?
2024-12-04T21:40:09.508-06:00  INFO 88219 --- [todo-management] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-12-04T21:40:09.509-06:00  INFO 88219 --- [todo-management] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-12-04T21:40:09.854-06:00 ERROR 88219 --- [todo-management] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.javaguides.todo_management.service.TodoService.addTodo(net.javaguides.todo_management.entity.Todo)" because "this.todoService" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.javaguides.todo_management.service.TodoService.addTodo(net.javaguides.todo_management.entity.Todo)" because "this.todoService" is null
    at net.javaguides.todo_management.controller.TodoController.todoAdd(TodoController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]

my code is as below
controller class:
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {

    private TodoService todoService;

    @PostMapping("create-todo")
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> todoAdd(@RequestBody Todo todo){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todoService.addTodo(todo), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

Service interface
public interface TodoService {
 
   Todo addTodo(Todo todo);

}

Service interface implementation
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TodoServiceImpl implements TodoService{
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public Todo addTodo(Todo todo){
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }
}

repository
public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo,Long> {
}

entity class
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private boolean completed;
}


Lombok isn't the issue here. The @AllArgsConstructor annotation means that you'll have a constructor that sets that field, but it doesn't mean that whatever calls that constructor will pass a non-null value.

I suggest you to de-lombok @AllArgsConstructor and set breakpoint in constructor. Then check why you get null.

I doubt that this is your actual code but a dumbed down and not representative version of your code. In sprng an autowired field cannot be null if spring cannot resolve a dependency the application simply won't start. Hence I believe your controller is different then what you show here and my suspicion is that your controller method is either private, final or you are using some annotations on it that creates a proxy for it like Spring Security annotations.

i'm sorry, i just started learning spring. can you please explain what setting breakpoint in constructor mean? or point me to a documentation or link? Thank You

Looks like some dependency or your environment issue. what spring boot version do you use, and can you share your pom file?
Same code worked fine for me with below dependency.
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> 


When you said, it was working for you, I created a new spring project from start.spring.io and selected spring 3.3.6 and java version 21, i'm still getting the same error. Previously i was using spring 3.4.0 and java version 17

can you share complete application start up logs and dependency listed in pom.xml?

Based on your log message
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.javaguides.todo_management.service.TodoService.addTodo(net.javaguides.todo_management.entity.Todo)" because "this.todoService" is null
    at net.javaguides.todo_management.controller.TodoController.todoAdd(TodoController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]

The issue is TodoService is not getting Autowired.
Either

mark this with @Autowired explicitly, or
@Autowired private TodoService todoService;

Change AllArgsConstructor to RequiredArgsConstructor and mark the todoService as final


@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {

    final private TodoService todoService;

    @PostMapping("create-todo")
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> todoAdd(@RequestBody Todo todo){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todoService.addTodo(todo), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

Follow similar step for TodoServiceImpl
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TodoServiceImpl implements TodoService{
    final private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public Todo addTodo(Todo todo){
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }
}

and please ensure that @Repository is added to repo layer
@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo,Long> {
}


Your second suggestion will create same constructor. It is good idea in principle, but doesn't solve the problem.
